# Proactive Prompt using Composer and Telephony Component in Bot Framework

Tags: botframework, telephony, bot-framework-composer

Is there a solution for when people don't talk on the phone for a certain amount of time to re prompt them for input? I am building a solution using Composer and the telephony component in bot framework and I would like to make it quite responsive when the user does not talk when I am expecting an input.

Do I have to use proactive messages?